# Encontrar substring com REGEX

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Eu estou tentando transformar todas as partes N_(...) em maiúsculas. Pensei que REGEX seria o mais apropriado. Só que está muito difícil, nem capturar a parte N_(...) para depois convertê-la em maiúsculas eu consigo:

Meu arquivo:

> abafada,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_abafado:fs
> abafadas,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_abafado:fp
> abafado,.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_abafado:ms
> abafados,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_abafado:mp
> abafante,.A+H_PRE+pol=no:+N_abafante:ms

Script:

```
import re

with open("word_upper.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

    pattern = re.findall(r'N_(\w+)', text)
    upper_word = pattern.group(1)

    print(upper_word)
```

Saída:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "teste_lemme.py", line 14, in
>
> upper_word = pattern.group(1)
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Saída desejada:

> abafado
> abafado
> abafado
> abafado
> abafante

Depois eu pensei em apenas transformar esta lista em maiúscula (usando o método (upper) e depois substituir com o método replace. Assim eu teria:

> abafada,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_ABAFADO:fs

O que vocês acham?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `re.sub` para substituir com base em uma expressão regular e, se passar como valor a substituir um objeto chamável, o valor capturado na expressão regular será substituído pelo retorno da função.

Algo como:

```
with open('words_upper.txt') as stream:
    text = stream.read()
    edited = re.sub(r'(N_\w+)', lambda match: match.group(0).upper(), text)
```

Assim, `edited` ficaria com o valor:

```
abafada,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_ABAFADO:fs abafadas,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_ABAFADO:fp abafado,.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_ABAFADO:ms abafados,abafado.A+H_PRE+pol=no+N_ABAFADO:mp abafante,.A+H_PRE+pol=no:+N_ABAFANTE:ms
```